# Modify JSON data representation in Python

Tags: python, json, object, nested

Assume I have this dictionary

```
{'person': {'field1': 'text1', 'field2': 'text2'}}
```

is it possible for `json.dumps` to serialize it like

```
{'person[field1]': 'text1', 'person[field2]': 'text2'}
```

I know I can do it by myself, but I'm asking if there's a built in way, because there is in javascript.

Comment: Loop through each person, add a new key person[field1] to a new json object ,and delete the old key in the old json

Comment: I'd be very surprised if there was a built-in way of doing this with `json.dumps` as it is not a standard way of serializing.

Comment: "{'person[field1]': 'text1', 'person[field2]': 'text2'}" is NOT valid json.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible with `json`. You'd have to do it yourself:

```
new_data = {
    f'{d}[{k}]' : v for k, v in json_data[d].items() for d in json_data
}
new_data
# {'person[field1]': 'text1', 'person[field2]': 'text2'}
```